# Estimating the Average and Standard Deviation of a Population based on a Sample with Missing Data with Known Ranks

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I need a way to shows me how the parameters of PDF, log-normal in this case, can be estimated based on a set with missing data points at the tail end of a sample.

For example, Consider we had 20 numbers with specified ***μ*** and ***σ***, and then missed two largest number of them. How do we can estimate the mean (***μ***) and standard deviation (***σ***) of these 20 numbers with only 18 available numbers, if we know that all of them obey a log-normal distribution?! (this is obvious that these 2 missing numbers are in the tail end of log-normal distribution)

*I am a structural engineering student. So please don't present complex solutions :) I want to code a program in Matlab to do this for me.

Comment: so you knowingly through away the two extremes? and then you want to infer the mean with the missing data present? The first question I have to ask are you doing some Winsorising the data to obtain a robust statistic? you can perform likelihood calculations .. this problem exists alot in actuarial settings when you are trying to determine the parameters of distributions when you do not have a comprehensive dataset. However, this is not my area of expertise so I will let others with more skill in that field. +1.

Comment: Have you tried the [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) options in Matlab's `lognfit` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognfit.html)) and related functions?